# How to restore single directory in a Fossil repo?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, fossil

Some commits ago, I deleted a directory in my [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org) repo. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

- open `fossil ui`
- go to the last commit in which your directory existed
- click on “zip file” to download a zip of the repository at that time
- decompress only the right folder.

Comment: Or go to "The union of all files from all check-ins", go the missing directory, select a deleted file, click on the version hash, select ancestors, click on the previos rev, download it as ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone your repository in folder 1
2. Open at the last checkin that contained the lost directory
3. Clone your repository in folder 2
4. Open the tip
5. Copy the lost directory from folder 1 to folder 2
6. execute addremove in folder 2
7. commit folder 2